# Concatenate all commentary about source files in a directory tree

Tags: bash, programming

I am working on a multitude of projects involving codes in Fortran. They are in a directory tree involving 10 to 20 folders, each of the codes is in a 'src' folder.

What I am looking for is a **simple** command that I could run at the root of the arborescence to go fetch all relevant information about the programs. This information is commented in the head of the .f or .f90 files, but of course it can run on a different number of lines in each file.

A difficulty is that it is not always at the very head of the file, since there are sometimes modules first. But the information always recalls the name of the file, or at least contains the word 'main'.

More precisely, let's say the arborescence is as follows :

```
/
|-folder1/
     |-program1.f
|-folder2/
     |-program2.f90
```

In `program1.f` I need the following block :

```
c
c program1 does the following
c blah blah
c
```

(this might be a capital C)

and in `program2.f90` I need the following :

```
!
! program2 does the following
! blah blah
!
```

Perhaps, there is a *regular expression* which could be used to fetch the full notice block?

Comment: You will have more luck getting answers if you give us more info about the "relevant information" you want. How is it formatted? do you want to get all the comments or a subset?

Comment: You're right. The relevant information is commented, i.e. the line begin with c C or !. I want a subset of the comment, because I don't need the comments describing the role of each procedure.

Comment: Is there an intended space before the first comment character on the first line in each example ie ' c' and ' !' or are they typos ? Would this be an Accurate rephrase of your your question ? "I want to extract all comment lines (lines beginning with c or C or !) from fortran files (filenames *.{f,f90}) in a particular directory sub tree." ?

Comment: No, there is no space before the first comment character. I couldn't avoid it when formatting my comment...  And no, it is not an accurate rephrase, because I don't want at all to extract all the comment lines. I don't need the comments in the code, neither the comments at the head of each procedure.

Comment: @illuminÉ Thanks for the bounty ! You point out an important point : it would be great to have in the output the file path and some minimal formatting.

Comment: @Illumin Isn't it better to expand out of Fortran in a new question (or as a comment); it makes no harm (you can link it). I don't understand what "interactive" comments meant in your text.

Comment: @illuminÉ I'm not certain, too. I was worried that there would be answers answering differet questions here, hence difficult to find the answer one is looking for. If you write the other question, I'm ready to put a bounty on it, too.

Comment: @imz--IvanZakharyaschev I hear you. Your edit is good. Because the title is more neutral than the content, I may even eventually try to provide an expanded answer myself or indeed maybe make a new Q as you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

You can give this command a try.  It may need tweaking for the particular layout of the comments you want (vs the ones you dont).

```
find . -type f -regex ".*\.[fF]\(90\)?" -exec awk '/^[Cc!]\ *program/{f=1} f{if(/^[^Cc!]/) exit; print}' {} \;
```

This will find all commonly named Fortran files in your directory tree and print the first comment block that begins with `! program`, `C program` or `c program` and prints the entirety of that comment block and only that comment block.  I chose those regexs based on your sample comment blocks.

If you need this tweaked, let me know in the comments or we can setup a chatroom to nail this down.  This should get you started with what you want though.  If your comments will not always start with `program` in them, you can try

```
find . -type f -regex ".*\.[fF]\(90\)?" -exec awk '/^[Cc!]\ *$/{f=1} f{if(/^[^Cc!]/) exit; print}' {} \;
```

which will instead start the match at the first line with only a comment character and optionally whitespace on the line.

**Note** These matches rely on the comment character being in column 1.  If you have free form files with the comment block that you need starting in a different column (not common for top level comments) then these wont work.

---

How this works:

```
find . -type f -regex ".*\.[fF]\(90\)?"
```

searches from your current directory (change `.` to an absolute path to be able to run this anywhere) recursively for any files named `*.f`, `*.F`, `*.f90`, or `*.F90`.  It then executes:

```
awk '/^[Cc!]\ *program/{f=1} f{if(/^[^Cc!]/) exit; print}' {} \;
```

on each file it finds.  Lets break this down:

```
/^[Cc!]\ *program/{f=1}
```

This matches the first line that begins with a comment character `C`, `c` or `!`, contains any number of spaces and then the word `program`.  This matches the first actual line of your sample comment blocks.  Awk prints this line and continues printing lines until

```
if(/^[^Cc!]/) exit;
```

is matched.  This matches for the first subsequent line that does not start with a comment character.  At this point awk exits and the next file gets processed.

Comment: Dear casey, this is great !  First, to answer your note : yes, the comment character is always in column 1.  But... I wasn't clear. In fact, my programs aren't named 'program1' or 'program2' ! Let's say that one is named 'readi.f'. Then the comment block will start with  'c readi does...'

Comment: I'm trying to adjust your solution to fit my need. You really put me on the good track !

Comment: @bela83 if you still need help with this, ping me in chat sometime tomorrow during the day (EDT) and we can work it out.

Comment: I still need help, but I don't have enough reputation to go to the chat room !

Answer (score 1):

If the information you need is on self-contained lines, then recursive `grep` is the way to go. For instance, if you want to find all comment lines something like `grep -r ^C` might do the trick. (I'm guessing at the comment syntax here. I'm old-school, but not *that* old-school).

If you need more complex logic, for instance "get all lines in the first block of lines starting with BLAH, but stop after the first non-BLAH line", then you have to invoke a command on each file in turn, probably `sed` or `awk`. For this, `find` is your friend: usually you would do something like

`find -exec awk '<AWK expression extracting what you need>' {} \;`